# Изменение позиции элементов в массиве в си

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм

Хочу максимально эффективно(с точки зрения скорости и нагрузки на память, без использования доп массивов)

Перемещать элементы в массиве чисел.

Допустим у нас есть массив чисел:

```
int a [5]  = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Дальше следует сканф и у нас стоит инструкция: 2(например)
Что означает что мы должны подвинуть элементы на 2 позиции, получаем:

```
int b [5]  = { 3, 4, 5, 1, 2 };
```

если имеем -1 на входе, получим:

```
int b [5]  = { 5, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Это делается при помощи 3 обращений. Вот код на C#

Функция, чтобы обернуть подмассив

```
void reverse(int[] data, int start, int end)
{
    while (end > start)
    {
        int tmp = data[end];
        data[end] = data[start];
        data[start] = tmp;
        end--;
        start++;
    }
}
```

Функция для смещения

```
void shift(int[] data, int pos)
{
    while(pos < 0) pos+=data.Length;
    
    reverse(data, 0, pos-1);
    reverse(data, pos, data.Length - 1);
    reverse(data, 0, data.Length - 1);
}
```

Проверка

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };    
shift(a, 2);    
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",a));

int[] b = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
shift(b, -1);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", b));
```

Вывод

```
3,4,5,1,2
5,1,2,3,4
```

Comment: спасибо большое, частично разобрался. Но все еще не понимаю как будет выглядеть код, если поменять логику шифта при вводе с минуса на плюс - что если я хочу вывести {5,1,2,3,4} имея на входе не -1 а +1?

Comment: @deniskalistrat ну добавьте `pos = -pos;` в начале функции `shift` и все дела. Или я не понял вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Массив со сдвигом.

```
int a[5];
int shift=-1;
int i = 3 ;
int x = a [ ( ( i + shift ) % 5 + 5 ) % 5 ] ;
// 3 -> 2
```

или с дополнительной функцией

```
int * Elt(int i) {
  return & a [ ( ( i + shift ) % 5 + 5 ) % 5 ] ;
}
x = * Elt ( 2 ) ;
* Elt ( 3 ) = 7 ;
```